# Vagrant with Chef/Berkshelf AWS security groups settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

I'm attempting to use Vagrant and Chef for the first time to spinup an AWS EC2 instance with mongoDB - specifically following this example https://github.com/jamestyj/vagrant-mongodb. Im on a mac and believe I have all PATH variables correctly set for the Chef-DK. Although, Im not entirely confident on my Berkshelf installation and if there could be some ruby conflicts after installing Chef...

Im running into a security group error when I attempt to "up" my instance to AWS. The following error is what's being thrown on spinup time

The security group 'sg-2d3fbc49' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-22771647' (Fog::Compute::AWS::NotFound)

According to AWS documentation, when booting an instance with a default VPC you must provide the security groups ID and not the name, which is what I've attempted with no luck.

I'm beginning to wonder if I havent installed Chef (solo) or Berkshelf correctly? Perhaps I'm not going through the correct deployment steps (i.e. -     berks vendor or any other steps a newby would overlook when getting their feet wet with Chef and Berkshelf.

Comment: where did you get sg-2d3fbc49 from?  If that's not a security group in your VPC, then you just need to change it to match one that is in your VPC.

Comment: The "sg-2d3fbc49" is the security group "Group ID". When I use the configured "Group Name" instead aws.security_groups = [ 'some-name' ] the instance will spin up which I can then interact with it through the aws console. Seems to configure Chef/Berk correctly since output related to the configured chef/berk entries. Now I'm hanging at "Waiting for SSH to become available..." I've deleted everything in my /.ssh/known_hosts/ to reestablish the relationship but also no luck.

Comment: make sure you have a public IP for the instance and that the security group in question is configured to allow you to ssh in (port 20).  If it still hangs like that, then try to ssh into it directly (by getting the IP from the AWS console).  If you can get in directly, then it's a Vagrant/Berks issue, otherwise it's an issue on your config.